# Is it possible to transfer files using RDP?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, windows-server-2012

I have a server located in a DMZ only accessible by RDP, and I need to transfer files to it.  My understanding is that the RDP protocol provides this functionality and that the client doesn't expose it.

Is it possible to initiate a data transfer over a firewalled RDP connection?

Comment: How big are the files? It can be done with small files, but bigger files just go splt...

Comment: The ISO of Visual Studio 2012... @athomsfere

Comment: Copy and paste works fine over an RDP session though performance is much better if you remotely mount a share and copy there instead. This is particularly noticable with heavy IO contention or across an ocean I have found.

Comment: How would I mount an ISO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirect C drive (under RDP options).  Copy ISO from C drive to RDP session (in session, go to Computer, then look for the Redirected C drive in the left window pane).

To mount the ISO, use something like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html)

Other option...If the DMZ server has Internet access stick the ISO on an FTP site, yousendit, etc.

Comment: The network path from the TS Host to your client is also ``\\tsclient\c\`` (for c:) which means you can use robocopy if you like

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is blocked by the party that configured the server you can map the local drives of the client as pseudo network-drives on the server. So you can copy your files over.
If they disabled the feature you are out of luck I'm afraid.

Copy-paste works too, but with ISO sized files it takes forever as the copy-paste symantics where never designed for this abuse.